# Third Party trackers blocked in private browsing mozilla

Tags: google-analytics, mozilla, intercom

we are using google analytics and intercom services as third party trackers in our project.But in private browsing in mozilla it is being blocked because of tracking protection and they wont allow third-party advertising or analytics services that engage in tracking.In the console you get the following message

> The resource at "http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" was
>   blocked because tracking protection is enabled.

Any ideas on how to change the code or enable tracking instead of changing options in mozilla's preferences will be a great help.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can track visitors either by creating image tags that point to the Google Analytics servers using the Google Analytics [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en) (MP) or use the MP to switch completely to serverside tracking.

However since your visitors have expressed a preference for privacy it might be unethical to circumvent this (and as per Googles TOS you still need to provide an opt-out from the tracking).